# How to prevent characters from repeating when entering text with a Bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: bluetooth, external-keyboard

I have an Android phone running 4.0.4 (ICS) and a [Microsoft Wedge Mobile Keyboard](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/wedge-mobile-keyboard/U6R-00001). I have paired the keyboard with my phone and it works all right most of the time.

However, every so often I will experience the following:

- after pushing some keys, nothing happens
- after a few seconds, the characters I have entered show up
- one of the characters is repeated many times

For example, pushing:

<kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd>

Will result in the following being displayed on screen:

> teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest

This only happens occasionally, but often enough to be a nuisance. I realize that there will always be unpredictable latency inherent with wireless communications (Bluetooth in this case) but I see no reason why characters are being repeated *as if I held down the key* (which I didn't).

Note that this is **not** a question about changing the repeat rate for keys being held down.

---

**Edit:** my device is a [Samsung Galaxy Discover](http://www.samsung.com/ca/consumer/mobile/mobile-phones/smartphones/SGH-S730HKMBMC).

Comment: This same thing happens to a computer at school using a standard keyboard, how very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [what I've read](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16364) so far, this may be a bluetooth issue.

Some people have fixed the issue by:

1. [using only 1 BT device](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16364#c27). If you have connected both a BT keyboard and BT mouse, disable one of them.
2. [disabling Wi-Fi](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16364#c34). Having both Wi-Fi and BT seems to trigger a repeating key issue.
3. [using External Keyboard Helper Pro](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16364#c28). It has a `do not repeat` option. [Link to app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper).

At the [end of the thread](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16364#c42), it mentions that BT was re-engineered in Android 4.2. So if you upgrade to 4.2, that should fix the issues you are having.

Comment: I am only using a single Bluetooth device (the keyboard). I could disable WiFi except that it would prevent me from doing anything online (like text entry in Google Docs). Neither my carrier nor Samsung appear to be offering an update to Android 4.2, so that's not really an option. I'll look into the External Keyboard Helper app you mentioned.

Comment: @NathanOsman Is External Keyboard Helper working for you so far?

Comment: I'm going to give their demo a try and see if it works.

Comment: @NathanOsman Is it OK now?

Comment: Finally had the chance to try the demo... and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Tab A and a Fintie Bluetooth keyboard.  It worked beautifully for more than a year but recently started repeating letters as described above.  After reading all the info I was able to find on the web, I was on the verge of just taking it apart to see if I could remedy the problem.  I had already checked my settings under tools but noticed after checking just one more time, there was a discrepancy under the Language section.  The Fintie was listed as English UK and, of course, when I set the keyboard up, I selected English US.  It had both listed with the UK option first and the US list second in grey.  I changed my selection to English UK and my repeating letters stopped. Must be that my Fintie is British!

I went to TOOLS, GENERAL MANAGEMENT, LANGUAGE & INPUT, PHYSICAL KEYBOARD.  That is where you can select your language.